# Kafka Consumer Processing - Noisy Neighbor Problem

Tags: apache-kafka, producer-consumer

We are using Kafka for capturing the data changes in the DB and those changes will be synced to the other services.

For syncing the data to the other services, after consuming the data we will do certain processing.

1 Partition will contain multiple customers data and if any customer suddenly produces more data, that customer slows down the sync for the other customers. We can handle by identifying that customer and offloading that process to the another thread or this problem can be solved only if we have one dedicated thread for one customer.

I would like to know whether this any efficient way of handling these types of problems. Is there any standardised solution that can be followed or any design pattern need to change for this use case

Answer (score 0):

You can offload consumer processing among threads, yes, see [parallel consumer](https://github.com/confluentinc/parallel-consumer).

But that wont solve your "overloaded partition" problem since the "delayed offsets" will still be stuck behind the "overactive" data that's still required to be read before the "less active" data. In other words, the consumer cannot pre-fetch data at later offsets or know when the "overactive data is finished".